# Deja Dup always creates First backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm running MATE Ubuntu 16.04 on an ASUS x-550LA trying to back up to an external HDD via USB.
Every time I run Deja Dup it Reports "Creating first copy".

This is what I find if I open the external HDD there are 149 such Volumes.
*****/duplicity-full.20200502T220644Z.vol1.difftar.gz

Plus when I try to "Restore" a test folder to "Previous version" it report "No back ups".

I'd really appreciate any help as no similar answers adequately cover my problem.

Comment: I have had similar problems if the permissions are messed up. Make sure the volumes on the ext. drive are not owned by root.

Comment: After the latest it now shows 536 Vols.

Comment: Organic Marble: They are owned by me.